# vert.x and BIO threading

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, vert.x

Lately I've started learning about `reactive`, `event-driven`, non-blocking Java frameworks and there is one that caught my eye - `vert.x`.

I guess the same question may apply to **akka (Play framework)** 'cause their philosophy or one of the goals is the same - and that is *reducing thread number and therefore highering scalability of an application*.

`vert.x` suggests that number of threads it consumes is ~equivalent to the number of CPU cores but it also bares in mind that sometimes you have to do a blocking operation so it encourages a developer to perform a blocking operation on a seperate working thread (worker vertical in terms of vert.x).

And that's where we come to my question:

- if I'm supposed to perform blocking IO operations on a new separate
  thread that means that every user that does a blocking operation has
  a new thread and therefore number of threads again becomes equal to
  the number of users as in a classical blocking thread model?

A real example would be a JDBC query - if 1000 concurrent users query  a SQL database via JDBC every user spawns it's own worker thread for that blocking operation. From my point of view there's no thread sparing, improved scalability or RAM sparing compared to classical blocking thread model. I must be missing something... Or not? Thank's in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sense to spawn 1000 concurrent threads queryng an SQL database - just because typical database cannot bear so many simultaneous connections, typical number is 10-15. The solution is to organize a special thread pool, where each thread has an open connection and serves tasks which access database. Tasks are submitted to a common blocking queue, and working threads read from that queue in a loop. Tasks are instances of

```
interface DBRunnable {
  public void run(Connection conn);
}
```

working threads pass their connection to the tasks:

```
public void run() {
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
  while (true) {
     DBRunnable task=queue.take();
     task.run(conn);
  }
}
```

Comment: Align number of threads in thread pool with the size of JDBC connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

vert.x suggest in terms of running threads on a machine and not in terms of users.

What they are saying is that if you have 16 CPU cores available and have 16 ready-to-work threads, then if you run a blocking operation on 1 of them, only 15 threads remain working at most and thus only 15 of your CPU cores are actually working. 1 of your cores is just waiting!

So to prevent having one idle core, they advice you to create one more thread and give it the blocking task so you still have 16 threads working on your 16 CPU cores.

The number of blocking threads is not really important (as long as it is not too large...) since they actually do not consume much of your CPU power.

It is different from usual blocking model because you isolated the blocking operations that do not require much resources on your side. What is left is sharing the remaining event-driven operations among the working threads you have.

Comment: Ok I have that clear, thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned - if you have 1000 users and all of them need to do a blocking operation as it is very often a situation, you need to spawn a seperate thread for each of those users 'cause every user needs it's own worker thread for querying a database (with JDBC). And then you end up having 1000 opened threads?

Comment: Yes, but doing nothing. When the blocking is done, they are just killed or reused for other users doing blocking IO, as would a CachedThreadPool do.

Comment: Remember to limit your JDBC connections on connection pool.

Comment: Limiting the connection pool makes sense, not limiting (until some point...) the number of idle threads. Those are two different problems and you want to avoid coupling and increase cohesion. So heandle each problem separately and let each of them lead their lives independently. The connection pool gets you the best of your database and having more idle threads just add concurrency to your app.

Comment: > "The number of blocking threads is not really important (as long as it is not too large...) since they actually do not consume much of your CPU power."

While blocking threads don't take "CPU power" per se in terms of computation cycles, there's the stack allocation and context switching that adds considerable overhead.  So to phrase a different way, a *small* number of blocking threads is OK so long as that number is fixed.  If the number of threads scales linearly (or more!) with the number of users accessing your system, you're headed for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As said before you should use a connection pool, however if you're interested in database access rather than specifically JDBC you could look at async db drivers such as:

- [Async MySQL/PostgreSQL](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client)

These drivers rely on netty so all its IO operations are non blocking, which means you don't need to have worker thread pools. Less threads means less context switching at the OS level which brings better performance.

Sadly there aren't many of these drivers around (I'm only aware for MySQL and PostgreSQL) so if you're forced to work with other RDBMS you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, please look into the async drivers for mysql and postgres, both which have a client specially made for vert.x. These 2 databases cover most use cases for a RDMS.

Another non-blocking option is MongoDB, which has a tailored non-blocking vert.x client. Works great, but ofcourse not SQL.